# Change file format from flv to anything android will play

Tags: android, ffmpeg, flv, playback, libavformat

I need to take this file which encoded is in h264 but in a flv container and just put it in a mp4, 3gp or whatever file format the android MediaPlayer will understand.

I want to do this natively. As I will not be decoding nor encoding anything I think I will not be wasting a lot of power (am I wrong?)

I followed the instructions from here http://www.roman10.net/?p=394 and could sucessfully compile and use ffmpeg and use it with mp4 and 3gp files.

But when it comes to flv files it fails. I understand there is no format definition for flv files in that specific port of ffmpeg for android.

There is no libavformat/flv.h header file for instance.

Maybe that's why this works:

> extern AVInputFormat ff_mov_demuxer;
>   av_register_input_format(&ff_mov_demuxer);

While this fails:

> ```
> extern AVInputFormat ff_flv_demuxer;
> av_register_input_format(&ff_flv_demuxer);
> ```

Question is, is there a light at the end of the tunnel? has someone done something similar? is it useful? I mean, I can always just throw the flv media file into a flash player and voila.. the thing is that this would be a parcial solution, as it will not work for all those folks running slower devices that can't yet run Flash.

Nelson

PS. Just in case. Here's some info about the file I'm talking about:

```
ffmpeg -i rio.flv 
ffmpeg version N-32624-gea8de10, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 15 2011 23:31:42 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
  libavutil    51. 16. 0 / 51. 16. 0
  libavcodec   53. 15. 0 / 53. 15. 0
  libavformat  53. 12. 0 / 53. 12. 0
  libavdevice  53.  3. 0 / 53.  3. 0
  libavfilter   2. 42. 0 /  2. 42. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 2000.00 (2000/1) -> 14.99 (15000/1001)
Input #0, flv, from 'rio.flv':
  Duration: 00:01:00.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 783 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 14.99 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc
```